# SSO with different account does not change token; returns data of previous SSO. Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, single-sign-on

I have an SSO login that works just fine...

However, when I try to login with a different account, it keeps using the data from the initial SSO. This seems to continue until the token has to refresh, at which point doing the SSO with the new account yields the correct data, but presents the same problem of a new SSO not returning the proper data.

I am stumped on this one, shouldn't passing in the new token from the new SSO properly reference what that token is referring to? Here is my AuthService:

```
 @Injectable()
    export class AuthWithEveService {

      activeToken: string;

      activeAuthHeader: HttpHeaders;

      constructor(

        private http: HttpClient
      ) {}

      verifyCharacter(token: string): Observable<Object> {

        return this.http.get(verifyGETUrl, { headers: this.activeAuthHeader});
      }

      SSOUrl(): string {

        let scope = '&scope='+scopes[0];

        return authorize_url
              + response_type
              + redirect_uri
              + client_id
              + scope;
      }

      initializeMemberValues(token: string) {
        this.activeToken = token;

        this.activeAuthHeader = new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
        });
      }
    }
```

And here is my AuthComponent:

```
export class UserHasAuthenticatedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthWithEveService,
    private apiService: APIAccessService,
    private data: FirebaseDataService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let access_token = this.route.snapshot.fragment.slice(13, 100);

    this.authService.initializeMemberValues(access_token);

    this.authService.verifyCharacter(access_token).subscribe(
      (obj: CharacterData) => {

        this.apiService.AuthedCharacter = obj;

        let charName = obj.CharacterName;

        this.data.adminDoc.ref.get().then(doc => {
          if(doc.data().adminCharacterNames.includes(charName)){
            this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
          }
          else{
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/success']);

          }
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

I must be missing something about SSO... Even with a new token from a separate SSO login, the 'verifyCharacter' callback object is returning the same data.

Comment: If I try this in an incognito window, I can login using the separate SSO accounts as intended... My browser instance must be storing some kind of auth data until the 20 minutes are up for the token life???

Reloading a normal browser does NOT allow for the same behavior as using incognito window...

Comment: What I have seen after some research on this is SSO login caches the authentication details in cookies. The cookies are sent over HTTP request to get the data of the previous user only instead of a new user.
You can check the cookies and find out the way to delete it. I was also facing the same problem but I didn't try the solutions yet.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: aaaah, I cannot remember... It was some minor detail. I forgot about this post, to be honest. I figured it out at some point, but forgot exactly what I did...